# Iterating through a nested list using filter or fold Racket

Tags: iteration, filtering, racket, nested-lists, fold

I need to iterate through a list with sublists in Racket using list iteration and filtering, one of the lists is a nested list, I tried using "`list?`" and "`car`" to iterate inside but of course that would only apply to the first value of the sublist.

Is there a way to iterate through the whole nested list using list iteration and filtering?

```
(define (count-evens lst)
  (length 
    (filter 
      (lambda (x) 
        (cond 
           [(and (list? x) 
                 (and (number? (car x)) 
                      (eq? (modulo (car x) 2) 0))) 
              #t]
           [(and (number? x) 
                 (eq? (modulo x 2) 0)) 
              #t]
           [else
              #f]))
    lst)))
```

```
(count-evens '(1 2 5 4 (8 4 (b (10 3 3))) 3))  
=> 3
Should return  => 5
```

I would use a recursive function to do this but the assignment doesn't allow it.

Comment: you are essentially asking to flatten an arbitrarily-nested list without recursion. I'm not sure I can see the way this can be done atm.

Comment: I will just use the flatten function with recursion because i don't see any other way to do it without recursion.

Comment: Why will you need a recursion if you will use flatten function?

Answer (score 0):

> "...assignment doesn't allow [recursive functions]"

Not sure what *is* allowed for this assignment, but
in *ye olden days* we processed recursive data structures with stacks...

```
(define (count-evens lst)
  (define (lst-at stack)          ;; (car stack) = index in deepest sub-list
    ;; produce list cursor within lst indexed by stack
    (do ([stack  (reverse stack) (cdr stack)]
         [cursor (list lst) (list-tail (car cursor) (car stack))])
      ((null? stack) cursor)))
  (do ([stack (list 0)
              (cond
                [(null? (lst-at stack))
                 (cdr stack)]     ;; pop stack
                [(pair? (car (lst-at stack)))
                 (cons 0 stack)]  ;; push stack
                [else             ;; step through current (sub)list
                 (cons (+ 1 (car stack)) (cdr stack))])]
       [count 0
              (let ([item (car (lst-at stack))])
                (if (and (number? item) (even? item)) (+ 1 count) count))])
    ((null? (lst-at stack)) count)))

> (count-evens '(1 2 5 4 (8 4 (b (10 3 3))) 3))  ;=>
5
```